# Parsing CSV header for validation

Tags: c#, csv

I have a simple application that reads a couple of csv files and outputs the input into catalogues for the website.  However, users have a habit of opening the csv files and inserting extra columns etc and it causes obvious issues, I have tried to tell people not mess with the files with no success, so i thought i would come up with a way round it.  Is there a better way of doing it than this?

```
    private static List<CatalogueLine> ImportCatalogueLines()
    {
        List<CatalogueLine> tempCatalogueLines = new List<CatalogueLine>();

        try
        {
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["catalogue-lines-import-file"]))
            {
                int? catCodeColumn = null;
                int? prodCodeColumn = null;

                // Validate the column headers
                string[] header = reader.ReadLine().ToLower().Split(',');

                for (int i = 0; i < header.Length - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (header[i] == "catcode")
                        catCodeColumn = i;

                    if (header[i] == "prodcode")
                        prodCodeColumn = i;
                }
                if (catCodeColumn.HasValue == false || prodCodeColumn.HasValue == false)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Unable to validate the column headers, cancel the import.");
                    return tempCatalogueLines;
                }

                // Loop the rest of the lines.
                while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                {
                    // Split the line
                    string[] catalogueLine = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                    tempCatalogueLines.Add(new CatalogueLine
                    { CatCode = catalogueLine[(int)catCodeColumn], ProdCode = catalogueLine[(int)prodCodeColumn] });
                    Console.Write($"\rImporting Catalogue Lines:\t{ catalogueLine[(int)prodCodeColumn] } ");
                }
            }
            Console.Write($"\rImporting Catalogue Lines:\tCompleted.                    ");
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ e.Message }");
            return tempCatalogueLines;
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{ e.Message }");
            return tempCatalogueLines;
        }
        return tempCatalogueLines;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to code review, unfortunately there is not enough code to review here, we prefer to see full classes to provide a better review. This isn't even a full function.

Comment: @pacmaninbw it is a full function though. But we'd need more information about the CSV to help you out Lee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Input Injection

Your function seems to depend at least on the input file, but this file is asked for by the function. You should follow the IoC principle and pass the file from outside (through function parameter).

```
var file = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["catalogue-lines-import-file"];
var lines = ImportCatalogueLines(file);
```

Maybe like that, but dont get confused, as your method Is private, this should be pushed even further, somewhere outside the entire class....

## Always False Conditional

```
if (header[i] == "catcode")
                        catCodeColumn = i;

                    if (header[i] == "prodcode")
                        prodCodeColumn = i
```

It Is impossible for header[i] to be equal to two different values at the same time. Use else if or switch.

## Duplicit Columns Check

Further if you are super paranoid you might want to check that catCodeColumn And prodCodeColumn Is not assigned more than once. That would mean there Is a duplicit column header (one that you care of).

## Redundant Comparisions

```
catCodeColumn.HasValue == false || prodCodeColumn.HasValue == false
```

The comparision to false Is redundant, use the negation operator "!".

```
!catCodeColumn.HasValue || !prodCodeColumn.HasValue
```

Or use de Morgans law

```
!(catCodeColumn.HasValue && prodCodeColumn.HasValue)
```

## Split by comma or do proper csv parsing?

In case some column value contains a comma character (not talking about the quotes needed for it to work), your implementation Will fail to handle it. Of course only if the csv ever contains such values. Even if it should not, you say that users can modify it as they like. Time to get paranoid!

## Error Reporting

You should not log everything to Console inside the function.  Especially not if you caught an exception, mute it and return possibly half-built result. Instead throw a custom exception, possibly let it carry the half-built list. But dont return with incomplete result. And put the logging to Its own scope.

## General Remarks

Other than that I think your approach Is quite reasonable. If you cannot hardcode or configure the columns offset ať compile time, you have to determine it dynamically... But ofc if you used a proper csv parser with additional features like header checking, the code would look quite different, probably shorter...

Answer (score 0):

In addition of @slepic answer, you might need to do something about the files themselves. So, instead of trying to fix everything from the code, you would be better if you secure the files or move the data to a database engine instead of using CVS.

For securing the CSVs files, you could move them into a directory and give read-only permission to everyone, and full permission to you and the application only. This way, they can view the files, but they can't make any modifications.

If they need to add some new rows to the CSVs, you could ask them to send the new data to you or someone else to add them to the files. At the end, you only need one person who can modify these files not everyone. You can also make `Excel` templates with `locked` cells that can be used to add new rows for everyone, so they would just send it to you to update current CSVs.

Best approach would be using a database and a solution to save the data and have a better control on it. This would be much easier to handle. Then, export the data to CSV whenever needed.

if you can't switch the data to a database, I would suggest using some CSV parser library such as `FileHelper` and `CsvHelper`. However, if external libraries are off-limits (for work requirements), you can add more handling in your code (along with above suggestions).

To validate the columns you can do this :

```
public static bool ValidateCatalogueLinesHeader(string line)
{
    var columnNames = new string[] { "catcode", "prodcode" };

    // Validate the column headers
    var header = line.Split(',');

    if (header.Length != columnNames.Length)
    {
        //throw new InvalidDataException($"the parsed csv has {header.Length} which is different than the provided number of columns"); 
        return false;
    }

    // non-null columns counter
    int countColumns = 0;

    foreach (var column in columnNames)
    {
        foreach (var headerName in header)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(headerName))
            {
                //throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(headerName)); 
                return false;
            }

            if (column.Equals(headerName, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
            {
                countColumns++;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    // double ensurance;
    if (countColumns != columnNames.Length)
    {
        //throw new InvalidDataException("Unable to validate the column headers"); 
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

then your code can be something like this :

```
private static List<CatalogueLine> ImportCatalogueLines()
{
    var filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["catalogue-lines-import-file"];

    // will cover null, empty string, and also the existing's of the file 
    if (!File.Exists(filePath)) { throw new FileNotFoundException(filePath); }

    List<CatalogueLine> tempCatalogueLines = new List<CatalogueLine>();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        var validateHeader = ValidateCatalogueLinesHeader(reader.ReadLine());

        if(!validateHeader) { throw new InvalidDataException("Unable to validate the column headers"); }

        while (!reader.EndOfStream)
        {
            var streamedLine = reader.ReadLine();

            // check this line first
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(streamedLine)) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(streamedLine)); }

            // notice, you're parsing integers, some integers could have commas separators 
            // in case you have more than one comma, you should handle it 
            // for time being, just throw an error

            // count number of commas 
            var countComma = streamedLine.Count(x => x == ',');

            if (countComma > 1)
            {
                throw new InvalidDataException("the streamed line has more than one comma.");
            }

            // only parse if there is one comma
            if (countComma == 1)
            {
                var line = streamedLine.Split(',');

                // ensure that this line has the same columns count
                if (line.Length == 2)
                {
                    // since it is two elements, we can specify them manually to avoid extra loops
                    // try parse them first to validate they are valid integers

                    var isValidCat = int.TryParse(line[0], out int catCode); 

                    var isValidProd = int.TryParse(line[1], out int prodCode);

                    // if both values are valid, add them to the list.
                    if (isValidCat && isValidProd)
                    {
                        tempCatalogueLines.Add(new CatalogueLine { CatCode = catCode, ProdCode = prodCode });
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return tempCatalogueLines;
    }
}
```

I have moved the header validation to a separated method because of readability, and also for code-reuse (in case you want to validate the header somewhere else). A better place for `ValidateCatalogueLinesHeader` would be inside the `CatalogueLine` class. And if there is mutliple CSVs models, then you can make an interface with `bool IsValid(string line);` or you can add `TryParse` method. this can improve your code.

Also, I have comment out thrown exceptions `throw new ...` which would give you some idea on what's happening in the code.